# Creating a RESTfull API with image in the response is not working

Tags: php, image, api, rest, slim

I am writng an REST API with SLIM Framework and PHP. I want to load a image from a directory and send it back in the Response.

Here is my code:

```
//Load SLIM-Framework
include 'api_model.php';
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app->get('/image/:supportID/:last_login/:device_token', function ($supportID, $last_login, $device_token) use($app) {

        $image = file_get_contents("images/Koala.png");
        $res = $app->response();
        $res->header('Content-type', 'image/png');
        $res->header('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="Koala.png"');
        $res->body($image);

});

//Start the routing per instance
$app->run();
```

Please ignore the parameter in the function, this doesn't matter.

If I test the request with RESTClient (Firefox), I get the following Response and not the image.

```
‰PNG  IHDR5Ø‚ZsRGB®ÎégAMA±üa pHYsÃÃÇo¨dtIMEÙ 07ÛÀ tEXtAuthorCorbis`É;Î tEXtCreationTime2008:02:11 11:32:43~¾j±tEXtSoftwarePaint.NET v3.5.100ôr¡ÿ'IDATx^Lýçs$G–ö‰ö_óîtS•ª Z#µÖZk­R!R Z ´&KW‘UE²§›Ýlj6uË™µµ}mÍî‡]»vï;÷9‘œ¶kæéá*Èßã~ÎñŸÙ5NÝHÀ8áÒRÒúã6Åy§æœ[;fW:µãÝ„S18Ç1hž ˜¦]úq§nÉeœpàvõ#VÍ°Y>¨—õY4ýNó¨Ï4ã5N;4”M?î5M¹µ#nÝUÑºœš—fØo™2k†q£ßÊBÂ‰Ó0ê1O¹ŒcvÝ šçÐ»t^ã¬[?kUŽÚµc^óŒÏ:åÐÙÔƒNÝPÐ4éÑ¡‘ã!Ë¬ß8Ìh$ÚŒªý–\w¨Ï»Ô~Ã¸Ç4ä7NSný$²ùTÃ^í¸W7m—ÛÅý~é¹ü\PÖŸHÝ‚Ó!Ñù˜|G'ï¤—ßçž÷Î$^á€•Õgc÷›gN#YØ}þy¯hØ/÷ŠF™4”†äcA]aÎ'\‚a+oÄ!×Ož1Ìö™9ªñ“’á_ˆG_QÍœÒM÷á£tä5ùØkÈ ~M=qJ3}F6~B:ôºrüUç¤‰;`á˜yçuÓ§3§lì3ú‰×ôS'4ÜsZN¿ž{VÏ:Û»E6ñº|ìÙè/t3çÍœ %g@É=iÙyÓÊñ3’É×5Ü~½à¼†? ‹ÇNÈ¦ÎˆÇO‰&ÎòGO ÆN³‡ß` ½ÎzC0~R0~B4IÅƒ¢©sâé>ÉôàœE>a ›DãnÏ¢ØØ1—ÈoæblñèýæYŸy2`Æƒð¦˜óY¯e_Eü¨Sˆ¸4±cv×2é6ŒøÌÓ!'âäl\Ÿ™°ò=F6Š :Ø!;×ñ¶„ìx¬SQ+êâxŒ£(?â¡´”ŸvÐ‹´±ÂvnÐÊ Ûù8G† c6é¥üb”@å;xQÏkqèûí¦·yÀc ;81— å“$¼Â°ƒõßi9“>ägEÝ3 /?”§’ˆsçQ÷tÀ:s³Ó>^È:q³ü.J7'æåá òÒ!q:$Å- )éÌEù¨r.¬,Äd™?ÏEdùˆ*í—Ç=ô"ãçGýÜdDž‹«²1U.,N¸gãN~>¨B¶\HUˆ©¨p.¦ÌEi¿4Pd‚ê„GRŒéJq=:[NjsaiÊÃ¯$´¸˜ËQN>.ÈE©mF´ ×‹q%R>®È†$I?'éá"ÂBL‘ Ë’ae9eÌE„I?­m¬å„®ž3µòº|HZ©‹aM=m,Ç”Å¨´‘"’jÖ´P0•“jt™r6¤¹¨(æ•Ó‚RR–Jç3ú¹¨•Î'å¤2•£™°(ã—ãÒù¤±œ0å#4©ž7.UÃKó‘åª¥âÆ·ù˜¨””¢BB]Nk qÍ|ÚTËX Q=œ«æ3êlXðrÑM”PI¨‹qy5m.'õ”¹š0bK M%­Ïh %žž®à#R1‰ôå´ %c5žŠ*DÕ¸q."™OËçS¼K¸ŽTŒ«1VÛJZëxHx.ÿJZ_Ípã\XMO<"AþJÖ€„É?•cêÞS(¥´¥¤®WZ>B'Ù0?åSÒRB•òÉP#¾*&8bÐ¨ñh[X‰‡‹®¡ýÔN¿0 l>iFÕX¼¥¸ŽÆ`¬ð>Ðë•RJôc…¨®˜n>¦ÇÃ*Åµt17S1ÃËkY}#k¨g4í‚q©dYˆ©s–µ’u)§Ý(›wLë%ÝzÑº^2íVìW—BWÖÓwºÙ»+åG«É7—’ooÎ=Û-<ÝÌ¿³Sz¾[ü÷£ú®µ>¼Úþíqýƒ‹?^ï~tcéã[+Hº±úû«Ýß_]üôöÆgw×?¿¿ùùƒõ¯ì|õhÿó‡_=<úâÁ®|ùd÷Ï¶>¹¿öÙýµïÞÙýúùîgV>{´ôéã¥?=hò¨óç«_¼ÝùèÞÂ‡ç?{ÒøüEóó+Ÿ¾½ýåó/žnþéñöW/ÿü«ËŸ<ÙÿýýÝì}xÿ÷ÿt÷ð7×·w{÷ƒë›¿¾²òÁõõ___ýåÕíÇÖoï/ÝÝ]º¿Ý|´Y~²W»º;e½t}»|}«r´”;heŽ–ò‹éjx¥ì]+{–Ê®Õª·[puŠÖæœ¾Ó4Ò–FÞRË˜Ê9ÍbQ¿P1”r’vU¹ÜÕÕÛ’FCº²nZÝ²,o˜:«ú¥Óú¦}mÃÖîZ–W\¦¡º m¶¬µŠ>Ÿ“—º…²¥š3âUÁL¥a âãå¢’|BRÌÊÉ|FZÉJJòFQÙÎ«›%E§ÄïÎÏ®VYk5ö^·4Ï[«röZÒÍ:o­4»Va/9¥<·œ6óªJNYžSf£Ât˜ŸŽ‹²iI:)Î&e©¸,‘…}ÂxH”MŠ1A"*CÂE¤DD˜ˆðqË¢!1¥07‚ÿ~ e*¦Œáï1ÎÎe¤sm2¡Ê&5‰ˆ<“TU –bÆ”©bE.¥ÅßWÒ+ÍÅÕs uÂ/Šâ?aT‘‹é£nA2ÈÉFy‰0ïv6¦É¦Ô~7/Sç’š—psãq4(‹¤Ñ $‘¢^$œ'"êhP‘)ÒqM<&G“âa8ÀxyÌ·rjpPýnÈ+H'pE€ úï§Å?á¹´}.nØ/B÷CLò¹øa¿e"¡R|ô»Eè)îg1%*$•ãJÈ7öáII.AØ+Ž•©ˆÆãà"…<è©<ìS=²°Wô("^UÔ§{åèZ4Ä
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Would you mind asking your question in english?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the language of SO is english not german.

Comment: Sorry I am new here =)

Comment: That looks like it could be binary PNG data. Perhaps check that you haven't accidentally sent output before your `Content-type` header, maybe via whitespace at the start of a file? Turn on all warnings/notices to see.

Comment: Based on the code that's what should happen. As @halfer said that is the binary data of the file you sent in the response. Would you mind descriving what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I'm doing. PNG files are base 64 encoded and require some things JPG/GIF's don't. Ignore the view part for the most part, but if it is false it will/should trigger a download.

```
$filename = "images/Koala.png";
// this is apparently not necessary
// $imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename));

$view = $app->request->get('view');

$res = $app->response();
$res['Content-Description'] = 'File Transfer';
$res['Content-Type'] = mime_content_type($filename);
$res['Content-Disposition'] = ((!$view)? 'attachment; ': '').'filename='.basename($filename);
$res['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = 'base64';
$res['Content-Length'] = filesize($filename);

readfile($filename);
```

Comment: Yes I'm aware this is a year old question, but it went unanswered and is high on Google's results.